# How to write a page whitelist in an asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website and as one of security options (prevent path traversal) I am planning to use a white list of pages which can be accessed. But my problem is I don't know how to do it. Can you share some articles or simple of code how to create a white list?

Comment: Use url rewrite option to achieve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many pages does the site have? If there are not too many pages and if pages are not added/removed frequently you can manually create a list of pages. If you are using master pages you can set this up in Page_Load method.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Dictionary<string,string> allowedUrls = LoadAllowedURLs();

            if (!allowedUrls.ContainsKey(Request.Path))
            {
                Response.Redirect("Some_default_redirect_page.aspx");   
            }
        }

    }
```

Now, if you do have a lot of pages you would need more sophisticated solution that uses web.config and more…

Comment: there is some around 15  pages.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you would like to allow certain users access to certain pages on your website - have you considered ASP.NET Security Trimming?